# PHP- Auto fill the data when ID is provided

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have two forms here. **Registration** and **Payment**. In the **registration** form i have fields hosteladmissionnumber,student name,sex,semester,branch.etc.. and in the Payment form,I have hosteladmissionnumber,Demand Draft number,DD date,Bank Name etc...

The question here is:
When i enter the hosteladmissionnumber in **payment** form, it must display the Text boxes of studentname,semester,Branch(only 3 fields) from the **registration** table in my database.How can i do this? Any suggestions? Do i really need to do this with three text boxes or is there any alternate way? Im using PHP as frontend and Mysql as Backend.

For payment part, the code is:(PHP)

```
<?php
session_start();
   $hostad=$_POST['hosteladmissionno'];
   //$sem=$_POST['student_name'];
   //$sem=$_POST['semester'];
   $ddno=$_POST['ddno'];
   $dd=$_POST['ddamount'];
   $bname=$_POST['bankname'];
   $dddate=$_POST['dddate'];
   $mess=$_POST['messamount'];
   $room=$_POST['roomamount'];
   $receipt=$_POST['receiptnumber'];

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

if(!$con)
{
die('Unable to connect'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('hostel',$con);


if(isset($sem)&&isset($dd)&&isset($bname)&&isset($dddate)&&isset($mess)&& isset($room)&&isset($receipt))
{
$r1="INSERT INTO payment(hosteladmissionno,semester,ddno,ddamount,bankname,dddate,messamount,roomamount,receiptnumber)
VALUES ($hostad','$sem','$ddno','$dd','$bname','$dddate','$mess','$room','$receipt')";
mysql_query($r1);
$r2="UPDATE registration SET status_flag=1 WHERE hosteladmissionno='$hostad'";
mysql_query($r2);
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
 // echo 'hello("',$rollnumber,'");', "\n";
 echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Successfuly Paid');</script>"; }
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: lol.. Hey sparky.. I have edited my post..do have a look!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, it more logical problem than technical.

1. Find the student by student by `hosteladmissionnumber`, I guess that is going to be primary key.
2. Show the student information on Payment Form.

use jquery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
<script>
    function getstudent(element)
    {
        var id = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'yoururl.php',

            data: { 'id' : id}, //send id

            success: function(data) {
                //parse the result
                //and display success function      
                //also get the student info and display 
                //it on other text value
                $('#stu_name').val(data.name);
            },
            dataType: 'json' //also can be xml
        });     
    }
</script>


<input name="hosteladmissionno" id="admissionno"  onblur="getstudent(this);"/>

<input name="stu_name" id="stu_name" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Yep.Hosteladmission number is my primary key.

Comment: But.. When i enter the hosteladmissionno in payment form. It must auto display the Semester,studentname and Branch.  i mean When i press Tab, it must check with the DB and display it

Comment: @Dinzy well there a lot's of work involved, first make your request working, and also work on server script.

Comment: @ExperimentX,?Here Id -hosteladmissionno and stu_name-student name. Right? How can i use Jquery in my code? using it for first time.

Comment: @Dinzy it's quite complicated, to explain in answer, you can come to chat on javascript room

Answer (score 2):

You need [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for this. You can dynamicaly.

See [this](http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/select.html) example or [this](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/DynamicPopulate/DynamicPopulate.aspx).

AJAX tutorial -> http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: http://remysharp.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/select.html - Hey sparky, Is there any way to get Code for this example? I want to do it that way.

Comment: Sure. Here is the tutorial for the exact same thing -> http://remysharp.com/2007/01/20/auto-populating-select-boxes-using-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

you can use AJAX. you can download jquery from this link http://jquery.com/

you can use jquery and java script code simultaneously without any problem.

Include downloaded jquery file same as java script file